# In CakePHP, element caching is not doing anything

Tags: caching, cakephp

Our software uses the following method for element caching in a cakePHP app:

Sample code:

```
<?php echo $this->element('cities-index', array('Cache' => array('time' => "12 hours")));?>
```

Based on the documentation, this should work just fine.

I've isolated this statement as a major cause of our web page loading slowly (this operation is costing us 0.2s per page execution), and I've come to the discovery that caching is doing absolutely nothing.

Caching is enabled in core.php and set to file, and the app/tmp folder has the right permissions. We've painstakingly gone through the cakePHP docs and are stumped.

We'd appreciate any assistance, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lower case 'cache' 
'+12 hour' rather than '12 hours'
Added a key

```
$this->element('cities-index', array('cache' => array('key'=>'cities-cache','time' => '+12 hour')));
```

Nik posted the correct answer first but in a comment to the original post. It may have gone unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your cache configuration, but for me caching the elements doesn't mean that you caching the controller's and models calls (where I think is the real bottleneck). Try to cache the database calls and probably your app will become faster.

Comment: We've enabled caching on a controller level as well, by referencing the Cache helper, as well as $cacheActions for all the intensive database calls. Forgive me if I'm wrong, but isn't element caching equivalent to "fragment caching" in the sense that it should bypass any and all computation and simply render a cached HTML output?

Comment: no it isn't, because controller code has been executed before the view code, so it has been executed as well as DB calls. Just make sure that you cache the results.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, we're already caching in the controller, but I'll look into whether that part's working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Caching is enabled in the controller, and I've double checked the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/view/434/requestAction   This page suggests that element caching should actually have been sufficient, it would prevent the controller (which uses caching anyway) from running requestAction. Now I'm stumped.

Comment: indeed of you use requestAction in the view this way the cache is enough. Try to write cache in lower case like: echo $this->element('latest_comments', array('cache'=>'+1 hour')); instead of your "Cache" in the question.

Comment: That isn't working either, I'm afraid. :(  However, I've recoded some areas to use Cache::read and Cache::write, which seems to have worked! It's weird, though, having to do it manually feels like it's not as elegant as it could be, and I'm unsure how to set cache durations in this case. I wonder why the built-in cache mechanisms don't work...

Comment: Oh wow, we've solved it. Just posting here in case anyone has the same problem. It was such a dumb mistake - you have to make sure the proper subfolders in app/tmp/cache exist and have the right permissions. The folders are app/tmp/cache/views, app/tmp/cache/persistent, and app/tmp/cache/models. Hope this helps someone! I am surprised that this doesn't give an error message or anything.

Comment: well, the first thing when you start a project is to chmod 777 the /app/tmp dir :) but in deed it's strange that it doesn't give an error.

Comment: Yes, we had actually done that since the start! The problem was an erroneous call in a library which deleted the subfolders, such as tmp/models, which previously existed. Since cakePHP had full permissions for the /tmp folder, we thought it would rebuild the subfolders as needed. But nope, it doesn't do that, and it doesn't even complain. :p Anyway, thanks for putting in the effort to help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your debug level set to? Certain debug level (1 or 2 - I can't remember) will disable caching.

This may also vary between CakePHP 1.2.x and 1.3.x - so know what version would be helpful too.